# How to shade a region outside the sphere in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, equations

I would like to graph the region given by (x-2)^2 + (y+1)^2 + z^2 > 5.  So, I'm looking to draw a dashed sphere of radius sqrt(5) centered at (2,-1,0) and then shade everything outside of it.  Any tips on how to do this using tikz?

Comment: This could help you: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/spherical-and-cartesian-grids/

Answer (score 2):

3D in TikZ is hard.  My proposal is (because the problem is rotationally symmetric) to show a projection onto the z=0 plane.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    axis equal,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    title={Projection onto the $z=0$ plane},
    xmin=-2,xmax=6,ymin=-4,ymax=2]
    \fill[black,opacity=.2,even odd rule]
    (rel axis cs: 0,0) rectangle (rel axis cs: 1,1)
    (axis cs: 2,-1) circle[radius=sqrt(5)];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks -- I was hoping to draw it in 3D because I'm typing up solutions to a homework assignment for my students.  I wanted to avoid drawing it by hand so that it looked cleaner.